# Computed property name ES5 in Node.js - when I call a function dynamically my console returns me TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, variables, call

I'm trying to put dynamically function call in Node.js in order to avoid a infinite list of switch-case.

Here a instance of file I want to reach :

```
var Object = require('../models/Object'); // it's a classic mongoose Schema's object
```

Here my dynamic function :

```
/***** post words *****/
router.post('/words', function (req, res) {
    var word = req.body ;
    var Theme = req.body.theme


    [Theme].add[Theme](word, function(err, words) {
        if(err) {
            res.json(err);
            throw err;
        }

        return res.json(words);
    })

})
```

We suppose a case where the object.name is "Object".

The function  I want to build have to call an addPost method in an another file. In order to dynamically call this files I have prepared a computed name property mechanism. Hence I always call the file corresponding to my need. If I have required Object and the user post with a Object's category value, okay it will go on the Object file to compute the Post toward the good destination. So my computed name property look as following :

```
console.log(req.body.name) // > "Object" 
Name = req.body.name 
console.log(Name)  // > "Object"
```

Okay now,

When I enter explicitly the name of the object to cal the function, as following :

`Object.functionObject()`

the function works fine.

BUT if I use a dynamically value call, like :

`[Name].functionOf[Name]()`

the function returns me :

> TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Also,

I have try with `${Name}` but my console returns me :

> TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function

I have tried to install ES6 on Node.js's side sames result for now.

How it is possible since the console.log return me the great value ?

Comment: How are you defining your dynamic functions

Comment: Thanks to answer, I have updated my post to include my functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Theme].add[Theme]()
```

This code creates an array with Theme as the first value and then calls functionOf, which doesn't exist on the array type. addTheme is actually a syntax error, but the engine never reaches it.

Although I recommend using a switch, I think what you're trying to do is something like this

```
// define Object1, Object2 with functionObject()
var objectCollection = {};
objectCollection[Object1.name] = Object1;
objectCollection[Object2.name] = Object2;


// Then you get req.body.name later
var objectName = req.body.name;
// and call the method
objectCollection[objectName].functionObject()
```

This will technically work, but there are a lots of failure possibilities and relying on reflection in this way makes me nervous because your client needs to know the inner workings (object and function names for instance). This is bad.

If the behavior of these objects is that different you should probably separate these into separate routes and let your client decide which it needs if you're making an api.

You could also create a factory to return the proper object and bury the switch statement there.

Comment: The properties in `var objectCollection` are all syntax errors.

Comment: So you advice would be to stick on switch's function if I understand you

Comment: `creates an array with Name as the first value` isn't actually true with OP's provided code as there is no delimiter on the `var Theme` line, it is actually trying to index into `req.body.theme`

Comment: @Webman After looking at your edits I could go either way. It seems weird to have your client passing a key of an object, but I may be missing something.

The answer from Zohaib Ijaz's answer actually removes the syntax errors you have so if that works for you that's fantastic and it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `Object` contains all those methods

```js
router.post('/words', function (req, res){
      var word = req.body ;
      var Theme = req.body.theme; // Post

      // Object.addPost();
      Object[`add${Theme}`](word, function(err, words) {
        if(err){
          res.json(err) ;
          throw err;
        }

      return  res.json(words);
      });
      
      // if you want Object.Post.addPost then
      Object[Theme][`add${Theme}`](word, function(err, words) {
        if(err){
          res.json(err) ;
          throw err;
        }

      return  res.json(words);
      });

    });
```